# HTML Input Number Padding

Tags: html, input

Creating a simple form.

Curious as to why the `type='number'` has different default size than `type='text'`?

Form looks like this. I believe with all defaults. Fiddle link below.

```
<form>
  <label for='number' >Age:</label>
  <input id='number' type='number' placeholder='Enter your age'>
  <label for='name' >Name:</label>
  <input id='name' type='text' placeholder='Enter your name'/>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnbkjcd3/2/

Comment: Which browser are you using? On both Edge and Chrome, it's the same exact size.

Comment: and in Firefox too

Comment: My guess is that you have some CSS style that's being applied to `type='text'` and not `type='number'`

Comment: I'm using firefox on Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: that's just the way it is.  Different browsers can - and will - implement different `<input>` types differently - sometimes *VERY* differently:

[Numeric Inputs – A Comparison of Browser Defaults](https://css-tricks.com/numeric-inputs-a-comparison-of-browser-defaults/)

[MDN: input The Input (Form Input) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

[MDN: input type="number"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

PS:

I looked at your JSFiddle in FF and Chrome and - at least for me - the text input looked identical to the number input.  I'm not sure why you're seeing them rendered "differently".

SUGGESTION:

Try to set font/size explicitly in CSS, and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn’t know, every browser has its own default `user agent` stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more legible. So field size may vary among browsers, see the following two screenshot:
Firefox: [image]
Chrome: [image]

To apply a standard stylesheet among all 'user-agent' you can use [cssrest](https://cssreset.com/).